# Confusion on RxJava onBackPressureBuffer and onBackPressureDrop

Tags: android, rx-java, backpressure

I want my code work like this graph, but it does not work ...
[image]

My Code:

```
    private fun <T> register(cls: Class<T>): Flowable<Pair<T, Long>> {
        return FlowableFromObservable(mRelay).onBackpressureBuffer(4).filter(
            /* filter target event. */
            EventPredictable(cls)
        ).cast(
            /* cast to target event */
            cls
        ).onBackpressureDrop {
            Log.i(TAG, "drop event: $it")
        }.concatMap { data ->
            /* start interval task blocking */
            val period = 1L
            val unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS
            MLog.d(TAG, "startInterval: data = $data")
            Flowable.interval(0, period, unit).take(DURATION.toLong()).takeUntil(
                getStopFlowable()
            ).map {
                Pair(data, it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getStopFlowable(): Flowable<StopIntervalEvent> {
        return RxBus.getDefault().register(StopIntervalEvent::class.java)
                    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    }
```

when I send 140 event in 10 ms, my code drop 12 event, not dropping 140 - 4 = 136 event that I expect. Why my code don't work like the graph above? Thank for your watching and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onBackpressurDrop` is always ready to receive items thus `onBackpressureBuffer` has no practical effect in your setup. `onBackpressurBuffer(int)` would fail on overflow so you'd never se the expected behavior with it. In addition, `concatMap` fetches 2 items upfront by default so it will get source items 1 and 2.

Instead, try using the [overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#onBackpressureBuffer-long-io.reactivex.functions.Action-io.reactivex.BackpressureOverflowStrategy-) with the backpressure strategy configurable:

```
 mRelay
 .toFlowable(BackpressureStaregy.MISSING)
 .onBackpressureBuffer(4, null, BackpressureOverflowStrategy.DROP_LATEST)
 .flatMap(data -> 
     Flowable.intervalRange(0, DURATION.toLong(), 0, period, unit)
     .takeUntil(getStopFlowable())
     .map(it -> new Pair(data, it))
     , 1 // <--------------------------------------------------- max concurrency
 );
```